# I am unable to receive the blob attachment in the mail

Tags: plsql

```
DECLARE
  l_attachment table_name.attachment_id%TYPE := '76564535';
  l_blob       table_name.attachment%TYPE;
BEGIN



  SELECT attachment
  INTO   l_blob
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  attachment_id = l_attachment;
  
  Pkg_Email_ora_attachment.send_email_with_attachment(p_sender_email     => 'abcd@yahoo.com',
                                                      p_from             => 'abcd@yahoo.com',
                                                      p_to               => Pkg_Email_ora_attachment.ARRAY( 'abcd@yahoo.com'),
                                                      p_cc               => Pkg_Email_ora_attachment.ARRAY( 'abcd@yahoo.com' ),
                                                      p_subject          => 'Test Message',
                                                      p_body             => 'This is a test message' ,
                                                      p_attach_blob      => l_blob,
                                                      p_attach_name      => '76564535');
                                                      
                                                      end;
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour_ and review [ask]. Following that greatly enhances your chance of getting a successful answer.  For debug help also add a [mre].

Comment: Are there any error messages? I can not understand what is the problem here ?

Comment: Though more details required to get into the actual problem, just a hint :- there is a limit with size of the attachment (as i remember from my past experience) and you may need to handle it by processing in **chunk** in the underlying implementation of the package **Pkg_Email_ora_attachment.send_email_with_attachment**